# Passing pointer to ndarray in a struct within a struct (ctypes)

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, struct, ctypes

I have a ctypes function that has a struct, containing another struct, as one of its arguments.
I have created the structs as follows;

```
class ChannelDataBuffers(Structure):
_pack_ = PACK
_fields_ = [
            ("bufferMax",  c_void_p),
            ("bufferMin", c_void_p),
            ("dataType", c_int32)
            ]


class DataBuffers(Structure):
_pack_ = PACK
_fields_ =  [
                ("channel",               c_int32),
                ("waveform",              c_uint64),
                ("downSampleRatioMode",   c_int32),
                ("read",                  c_int32),
                ("buffers",               ChannelDataBuffers),
                ("nbuffers",              c_uint32),
                ("nDistributionPoints",   c_uint32)
            ]
def __init__(self, channel, waveform, ratiomode, read, ref_buffermax, ref_buffermin, datatype, nbuffers, nDistributionPoints):

    self.channel = c_int32(channel)
    self.waveform = c_uint64(waveform)
    self.downSampleRatioMode = c_int32(ratiomode)
    self.read = c_int32(read)
    self.buffers.bufferMax = (ref_buffermax)
    self.buffers.bufferMin = (ref_buffermin)
    self.buffers.datatype = c_int32(datatype)
    self.nbuffers = c_uint32(nbuffers)
    self.nDistributionPoints = c_uint32(nDistributionPoints)
```

The bufferMax and bufferMin are both numpy arrays, passed using the .ctypes argument - ie defined as follows:

```
bufMax = self._buffers[bufIndex].data.ctypes
```

This results in an object being passed into the DataBuffers init function of

```
numpy.core._internal._ctypes object at 0x08D99D90
```

Which seems sensible.
However I then hit an exception of

```
 cannot be converted to pointer <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>
```

at the line

```
self.buffers.bufferMax = (ref_buffermax)
```

Anyone know what I can do to fix this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you need to use `ctypes.cast`:

```
self.buffers.bufferMax = ctypes.cast(ref_buffermax, c_void_p)
```

Comment: Thanks - appears to have worked (it no longer excepts there, although the driver isn't getting the correct value from the inner struct)